# How to send array of files as well as json data using axios in React FE and Flask BE?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, axios

so as the title explains, I am trying to send both JSON data and an array of files using Axios to my Flask BE server. I am not sure where the problem lies, whether it is in FE or BE, but I cannot seem to send the files. I am trying to send it in a FormData object but if I try to send the array of files together, it shows:

```
[object File, object File, ...]
```

When I send them individually, it sends as binary which is what I want. But I cannot send binary data in the array.

If possible, please let me know how I can send it and read it in my Flask server in BE.

EDIT:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));

const files = data?.additional_document;

if (Array.isArray(files )) {
 const arrayKey = `additionalFiles`;

 files.forEach(v => {
   formData.append(arrayKey, v);
 });
}

         
dispatch(apiCallToBackEnd(formData, (res) => getPDF(res)));
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Sure, check the edit above^ Not really sure how to read it in the Backend